How do I clear out all items in a NET Maui Picker in C#?
I want to do something like I can in NET Framework.
DropDownList.Clear();
I am not using MVC.
Please do not give answers that have anything to do with MVC.

you clear its ItemsSource

MVC is generally not a pattern anyone uses in MAUI

you should really call Clear on whatever the underlying datasource instead of just setting it to null

According to the documentation, the ItemsSource property gets or sets the source list of items to template and display, so presumably setting it to an empty list should do the trick:
picker.ItemsSource = new List<string>();

Or, since it implements IList, you should be able to call the Clear() method:
picker.ItemsSource.Clear();

Note, I haven't tested this, but just opened the documentation. Definitely a good way to learn about code modules!

ItemsSource.Clear(); doesn't work. Setting ItemsSource = null OR setting it to a blank list also works. But the next question is do either of these methods to clear it cause a memory leak? This is a one page Maui app so the picker never "goes out of scope" stackoverflow.com/questions/57616986/… I am going with setitng it to a blank list... Thanks everyone. –
